# Homeomorphism of surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

I do not know how to work out the following problem.

Determine for which values of $g, g', n$ and $n'$ the interior of the surfaces $g$#$T^2$ with $n$ punctures and $g'$#$T^2$ with $n'$ punctures are homeomorphic.

I tried working out the fundamental group of the spaces, and as these are not closed surfaces I can not use the classification of surfaces. So I am now stuck and help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, please explain your notation $g\#T^2$. Do you mean a connected sum of $g$ copies of $T^2$?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.

Comment: Next, why can you not just calculate the fundamental group of the spaces? That's always a topological invariant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd prefer to write $\Sigma_{g,n}$ for what you write $g\# T^2$ punctured $n$ times. Set $n > 0$ from now on. I'm going to provide a small sketch but leave most of the details to you.

1) Calculate the fundamental group of $\Sigma_{g,n}$; you will find that they are isomorphic for $(g,n)$ and $(g',n')$ if and only if $2g + n = 2g' + n'$.

2) Prove that genus still makes sense for noncompact surfaces in the following sense: if $S$ is a noncompact surface, it might be possible that $S$ embeds into some $\Sigma_g$ for some finite $g$. Take the infimum over the set of $g$ such that there is an embedding $S \hookrightarrow \Sigma_g$; call this the genus of $S$. (If there is no such embedding, say that $S$ has infinite genus.) Now you should try to calculate $\text{genus}(\Sigma_{g,n}) = g$. Clearly genus is a topological invariant.

Thus if $\Sigma_{g,n} \cong \Sigma_{g',n'}$, $g = g'$ by (2) and thus $n = n'$ by (1).

A different approach, less special to surfaces but perhaps enlightening in a different direction, is to realize that $n$ - the cardinality of the set of *ends* of the surface - is also a well-defined topological invariant (instead of the genus). I find this a little bit less visually intuitive, but you might find it easier. Then (1) + this gives you the result you want (or you could talk about "compactifying each end" separately, which makes sense once you know that ends make sense).